# When Mapping over a react component how and where can i call a function to return a property value in the same component file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working with a data structure that looks like this:

```
allPersons:[
    { discoveriesByType:[
        {type:'car',pending:0,confirmed:10, discoveries:[{data...}]},
        {type:'truck',pending:1,confirmed:25, discoveries:[{data...}]}
      ]
    },
    { discoveriesByType:[
        {type:'suv',pending:0,confirmed:10, discoveries:[{data...}]},
        {type:'atv',pending:1,confirmed:25, discoveries:[{data...}]}
      ]
    }
]
```

This data structure is represented in the component file as `props.resultItemData` which looks like this and returns the `ResultItem` component.

```
<>
{ props.resultItemData.map((data, index) => {
      return(
        <ResultItem carOnlyPendingValue={this should be the value of discoveriesByType.type === 'cars' pending: its value} atvOnlyPendingValue={value} />
      )
  }
}
</>
```

Where in this file would I create a function to grab only the `discoveriesByType.type === "suv"` value of `pending`?

Comment: Can you expand the code to show more bits of this file? For instance, what is `value`?

Comment: @acdcjunior That's what i'm asking how and where can put the function to get that value for the type:car's pending value. Sorry, this is a hard one to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to calculate the value and place it in a variable before the render function. No need for `useState` or other. See working demo:

```js
function ResultItem({ carOnlyPendingValue, atvOnlyPendingValue }) {
  return <div style={{ border: '1px solid black' }}>
    ResultItem (Person):<br />
    <pre>carOnlyPendingValue: {carOnlyPendingValue} - atvOnlyPendingValue: {atvOnlyPendingValue}</pre>
  </div>;
}

function getPendingValueForType(discoveriesByType, type) {
  const discovery = discoveriesByType.find(d => d.type === type);
  return discovery ? discovery.pending : `<discovery '${type}' not found>`;
}

function MyComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
    { props.resultItemData.map((data, index) => {
        const carOnlyPendingValue = getPendingValueForType(data.discoveriesByType, 'car');
        const atvOnlyPendingValue = getPendingValueForType(data.discoveriesByType, 'atv');
        return(
          <ResultItem carOnlyPendingValue={carOnlyPendingValue} atvOnlyPendingValue={atvOnlyPendingValue} />
        );
      })
    }
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const data = {
    allPersons:[
      { discoveriesByType:[
          {type:'car',pending:0,confirmed:10, discoveries:[{data: 'c'}]},
          {type:'truck',pending:1,confirmed:25, discoveries:[{data: 't'}]}
        ]
      },
      { discoveriesByType:[
          {type:'suv',pending:0,confirmed:10, discoveries:[{data: 's'}]},
          {type:'atv',pending:1,confirmed:25, discoveries:[{data: 'a'}]}
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
  return (
    <div><MyComponent resultItemData={data.allPersons} /></div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

If instead of a simple `.find()` you do complex calculations, you can wrap it with [`useMemo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).

Comment: I'm only trying to get the value of pending if the type is car. Not the data in discoveries.

Comment: But it should only be returning one carOnlyPendingValue not 4 values considering only one object has the type:cars

Comment: It is -- one line per person, actually. I updated the answer to make it clearer. I moved the code that extracts the value of `pending` to a `getPendingValueForType` function.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much! I was stumped